# My fireplace works great till I put the ceramic logs in, then it shuts off including the pilot

Tags: fireplace, propane

My propane fireplace was shutting off after a few minutes, including the pilot light.  I took all the logs out.  The pilot stayed on.  I lit it and it stayed on.  I put the logs back in and it won't stay on.  I took the logs out one at a time and tried it.  No good.  Only works with no logs.  Over the years it has worked fine with occasional cleaning.

Comment: How quickly after replacing the logs is it going out? Are you blocking the pilot from a optical flame detector? Not all pilots are thermopile type tc based on heat, are the logs disrupting the air flow so the pilot if a tc is not in the flame?

Comment: I don't believe there is an optical detector.  It lasts a few minutes with the logs.  The log pattern hasn't changed, a large one front and rear and five small ones running between the large ones. They only fit in one pattern.  I got it to stay on with the front large log only.

Comment: Can you see the flame hitting the TC ? I have seen both gas log and furnaces that when logs or covers are installed diverts the flame from the probe, the other case was the optical that some log configuration blocked the light and shutdown, your case sounds like ether an exhaust flow sensor or a high temp issue but we can only guess with the limited info provided.